# Topographic Maps to use for Mountaineering Guide Book?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Do you know how to create topographic maps to be included in LaTex books?
Alternatively, where can I get topographic maps to be used in a book?

I would like to write a small backcountry skiing (mountaineering) guidebook for selected regions in Canada and the US.
The maps used in Switzerland are the best that I have seen so far.

Do you know whether there are maps that can be used in TikZ to create route descriptions?

https://map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&bgLayer=ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege&layers_opacity=1,1,1,0.8&layers_visibility=false,false,false,false&layers_timestamp=18641231,,,&E=2645289.49&N=1154184.93&zoom=5.912713227542987

Thank you!
Matt

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. I think that the answer is simply no. :-(

Comment: What exactly to you intend to start with?  Given a grid of altitude values you can generate a contour map with pgfpplots and add names at known locations.

Comment: I think it is beyond the scope of TeX to create an actual map, as it were. Your best bet is probably to obtain (i.e., either create externally or license) a map file and simply embed the image.

Comment: ok, thank you! I will try to find different solutions.